# How can I see my php scripts files in MAMP?

Tags: php, mamp

I'm trying to learn PHP and I've installed MAMP (5.0.4)
I see that my files are in MAMP\htdocs

if I create an index.html file in place it in that direction how to I get it to show.

1. I fire up MAMP (server and mSQL are on)
2. I click on the OPEN WebStart Page

it opens http://localhost:81/MAMP/
If I type in index.html after that (http://localhost:81/MAMP/index.html)
I've also tried adding htdocs in the path
I am getting a 404 error.

I know it's got to be something simple

Answer (score 0):

When MAMP loads up it actually gives you options to go to the website or myphpadmin site

if you want to jump directly to your site then just use.
None of this will work if you do not set the project in preference to the directory of the project you are working on

```
http://localhost:81/
```